# Login Functionality not working

Tags: php, ajax

So I took the login script demonstrated in this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2014/07/ajax-php-login-page.html

However, when I try to run it, I keep getting an incorrect login information error. The database, the table, all of that is correct. I'll look at it again, but I'm sure that's fine.

I haven't changed anything besides the name of the table, and my db info.

- Why does the PHP dissapear? **Solved**

Comment: Why would PHP "appear" in the browser? It's supposed to be executed in order to do stuff on the server, not on your browser. Your browser gets the HTML, not PHP.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: To nitpick, the update to the question may be better as its *own* separate question. Just to not confuse the validity of existing answers. More to the point, you'll need to provide some debugging information. Check the PHP logs for errors, use in-browser debugging tools to examine the AJAX requests and responses, etc.  Basically narrow down the problem.  We very much want to help, but "Here's my code, why doesn't it work?" is often a *very* difficult question to answer.

Comment: Yeah I'll make a new question. I removed the edit. The issue I am having is that theoretically there shouldn't even be a problem. The only thing I changed was my log in credentials, the table that I get the info from, and everything else is the same. I guess there must be something I'm overlooking. I'll be back in <90 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

> the php at the top of index.php goes away when I look at the source code on a browser

This is a good thing :)

PHP code is processed server-side.  The *result* of that code (which is usually HTML) is then sent to the browser.  PHP code itself should never be sent to the browser for a couple of reasons:

1. It would expose your server-side code to users, which could help them do malicious things.
2. The browser wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Are you saying that the code is there, it's just not visible to the users?

Comment: @taytay: The code is "there" in the sense that it's executing server-side.  It's "not there" client-side, because it's already executed. If the page is successfully displaying, and there are no errors in the server-side logs (PHP logs, web server logs, etc.), then the PHP code *is* successfully executing.  Whether or not it's doing what you intend it to do is another story entirely, one which would require more information about the problem (and potentially its own Stack Overflow question), including the code being used and the *specific* way in which it's "not working".

Comment: @taytay: Illustrating with a simpler example... If you have code like `echo 1 + 1;` then that code is executed on the server.  First the addition is performed, so it evaluates to `echo 2;`, then the `echo` is performed which emits the value to the client (which is the web browser).  All the web browser ever sees or knows about is simply `2`, which is the result of the code.  The browser has no knowledge of the code which *produced* that result.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. It clears it up so much.